# Why do I get a 500.19 Internal Server Error when publishing to IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Here is the contents of my web.config file which was generated automatically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\RRRRAdminFrontend.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 2b13cd10-9360-4795-8443-00aebad0bb00-->
```

**Error Message**

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.



Detailed Error Information:



Module
   IIS Web Core 

Notification
   Unknown 

Handler
   Not yet determined 

Error Code
   0x8007000d 

Config Error
    

Config File
   \\?\C:\inetpub\RRRRAdmin\web.config 



Requested URL
   http://rrrradmin.sharevista.com:80/ 

Physical Path
   

Logon Method
   Not yet determined 

Logon User
   Not yet determined 

Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong or if I need to change anything with this? I'm not too familiar with working with IIS so I can show other code snippets if it would help.

Comment: @LexLi Yeah that was the issue. I had to install the 2.2.8 core runtime since it was developed in Asp.Net Core 2.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to host Asp.net core application on IIS, you need to install the ASP.NET Core Module/Hosting Bundle.

Download the installer using the following link:

[Current .NET Core Hosting Bundle installer (direct download).](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.1-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)

For more details instructions on how to install the ASP.NET Core Module, or installing different versions, see [Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: This did the trick! I had to install the 2.2.8 core runtime since it was developed in Asp.Net Core 2.2. Thank you!